# How do end-to-end encryption (E2EE) IM apps implementing push notifications?

Tags: android, ios, whatsapp, end-to-end-encryption, signal

Say WhatsApp and Signal on Android devices, how do they keep the E2EE not be broken?

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451413/how-can-whatsapp-encrypt-push-notifications-on-ios) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500733/how-can-whatsapp-use-end-to-end-encryption-when-sending-notifications-containing) claimed that WhatsApp uses VoIP background mode on iOS to make the push notification invoke the app to decrypt the message and send a local notification, but this seems to be outdated. I am not familiar with iOS, but based on my test, similar things happen on Android devices, taking Signal as an example:

- Given the permission to be started by other APPs to Signal: Then the push notifications work well. And the Signal appears in the process list.
- Once the permission is revoked (nothing can implicitly start WhatsApp, even FCM): Push notification just fails. FCM log said things like "cannot broadcast to stopped app ".

That being said, I guess current policy for the push notification of E2EE IM is still:

1. FCM notifies the device to open APP
2. APP decrypt the message and send a notification locally.
3. The APP may continue to run a period of time?

However, I cannot find any document regarding my guess. Could someone tell me the truth or give me some references or technical documents on this issue?

Comment: I googled "whatsapp encrypted push notifications" and the duplicate was the top hit.

Comment: @schroeder Me too, but it seems out-dated?

Comment: And that information should have led you to the google search "whatsapp pushkit" which will return far more recent technical details...